# Avoid installing composer's require-dev libraries in production

Tags: php, composer-php

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19117871/241142), packages listed in composer.json's `require-dev` section will still be installed when you do

```
composer install
```

Since `composer install` is a normal thing to do as part of a production install, to install all versions specified in the composer.lock file, how do you avoid installing things you only need for development?   I'm accustomed to Gemfiles, where specifying something for dev means it is ignored in production, and can't quite wrap my mind around why anyone would ever want to install *everything* in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha... I missed the `--no-dev` flag previously.   Apparently you have to specifically tell `composer install` that it should ignore the `require-dev` sections.  In a way this makes sense, since you more often type `composer install` on your development laptop, and `composer install --no-dev` will probably be a part of a deployment script where you don't need to think about it.  So the defaults are set up for developer convenience.

Comment: Installing dev packages by default and having a switch to not install them in production environments makes it easier for those experienced with Composer and harder for those starting out with Composer.