# How to have 2 composer.json files in 1 project?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm working on a project that's a WordPress plugin. This is my directory structure:

```
├── src/
│   ├── plugin-name.php
│   └── readme.txt
├── tests/
└── ...
```

I want to include a composer.json file with the plugin so that users can install with Composer if they wish. For example:

```
├── src/
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── plugin-name.php
│   └── readme.txt
├── tests/
└── ...
```

But I also want to use the `vfsStream` component when I'm unit testing the plugin. This will mean I'll need to require `vfsStream` in a composer.json file that's in my root. For example:

```
├── src/
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── plugin-name.php
│   └── readme.txt
├── tests/
├── composer.json
└── ...
```

I'm not sure a single project can have 2 composer.json files. Is having 2 composer.json files the right way to go about this?

Comment: It is not clear why you are creating two composer packages? Are they both on Packagist?

Comment: One in my root directory so I can use a particular component in my unit tests and another in my `src` directory. The contents of `src` get uploaded to wordpress.org which means users can install my plugin via Composer (should they wish).

Comment: In that case, I reworded my answer to encourage you to require your Wordpress Composer package in your develop project instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have one composer.json in your project root and add develop dependencies for tests using `require-dev`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev

Comment: This indicates I should have just one composer.json file in my root. The problem is, my root composer.json isn't distributed with my plugin. Only the contents of the `src/` directory is distributed

Comment: OK, wasn't aware of that. You can have multiple composer.json files, that shouldn't be an issue.

if you run e.g. `composer install` it will use the composer.json in the  folder you're currently in

Answer (score 1):

### New Answer:

I think the best way would be to turn the actual Wordpress plugin into a Composer package, and then require it in your dev-mode project.

The only difference is that it wont be in the 'src' directory but tucked away in the 'vendor' directory.

AFAIK, Composer does not handle nested 'composer.json' files yet, if ever.

### Original Answer:

The *right way* is to make a 'require-dev' section, like this:

```
  "require-dev": {
    "whoever/vfsStream": "*"
},
```

*after* the `require` section in your one and only composer.json file.

This requires that people use the `--no-dev` flag when installing for production, though.

See [Using "require-dev" to install packages in composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117871/using-require-dev-to-install-packages-in-composer)

If you use the `require-dev` section for develop packages, you are giving people a choice to not use them. They can just pass the 'no-dev' flag when requiring your package.

Edit:
If you are using `src` as the main directory of your package, you can set that up in your 'composer.json' in an 'autoload' section like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "yourname\\yourpackage\\": ["src/"]
    }
}
```

Edit Again:
It looks like using Composer to install Wordpress plugins is not totally without problems:
[A Narrative of Using Composer in a WordPress Plugin](http://wptavern.com/a-narrative-of-using-composer-in-a-wordpress-plugin)

However, if you insist, there might be tricks up the sleeve of this post:
[Using Composer to manage Wordpress themes and plugins](https://deliciousbrains.com/using-composer-manage-wordpress-themes-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks for the info on `require-dev`. I was actually already aware of that and am using it. The problem is, my root composer.json isn't distributed with my plugin. Only the contents of the `src/` directory is distributed

Comment: Why? I mean, if you have a composer package set up in the root, then I don't understand the need to put a second composer.json in the 'src' directory.

Comment: The contents of my `src` directory get uploaded to wordpress.org whereas the stuff in my project root such as composer.json, the `tests` directory etc don't .

Comment: I understand that part. What I don't understand, however, is how installing a Wordpress plugin by means of Composer works. I think that is the main issue :)

Comment: OK. I just read up on how people are using Composer and Wordpress together - and it does not seem to be all harmony: http://wptavern.com/a-narrative-of-using-composer-in-a-wordpress-plugin

Comment: you're right, using composer inside a WordPress plugin does have many many problems.