# Use composer to require package with tests included

Tags: testing, composer-php

I want to reuse test code (e.g. mock classes) from a package. But i don't know how to tell composer to fetch the dependency with tests included.

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
   "some/package": "2.0.0"
}
```

composer.json of the other package (which has `/src` and `/tests` subfolders):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Some\\Namespace\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Some\\Namespace\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

This gives me only the `/src` folder under `/vendor/some/package/`.

I tried specifiying `some/package: 2.0.0@dev` without any effect.

Is this even possible with composer (and packagist)?

Answer (score -1):

Use require-dev this will then also install the the development packages when `composer install` is run.

`"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.7.*"
  },`

As described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19120691/409556

Comment: If i include `mockery/mockery` into `require-dev` it does not install the `require-dev` dependencies from the `composer.json` included in `mockery`