# require and require-dev dependencies of composer Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a Laravel App and I want to install require dependencies but I was wondering how does composer know whether to load dev dependencies or production dependencies?

just got confused by this concept so if somebody could clarify this concept for me than that would be of great help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between require and require-dev sections in composer.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117871/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-require-dev-sections-in-composer-json)

Answer (score 2):

When you run `composer install --dev`, composer installs all packages including `require-dev`. This is the default behaviour, exclusion of the flag would result in the same action.

When you run `composer install --no-dev`, composer skips the `require-dev` packages.

Also, composer will not install the `require-dev` package of a `required` package unless you specifically ask it to do so

Comment: Was wonder about the the `require-dev` package of a `required` package. Is it documented somewhere that it wont be installed?

Answer (score 0):

The regular `require` dependencies are such packages that you will ALWAYS use, meaning that the framework itself (in this case Laravel), your application code and/or other 3rd party code is dependent on such packages. These dependencies are often referred as prod dependencies since you use them in production (because without them, your app wouldn't run)

The `require-dev` dependencies are "optional", in the sense that your core application logic would run, but you would not be able to run "development" stuff, such as Unit tests (`phpunit/phpunit` package) and instantiate fake data (`fzaninotto/faker`).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I understand the difference but how does composer know whether the environment is production or development?

Comment: composer install will install the composer.json dependencies , so what I don't understand is how does composer know what the current environment is ?

Comment: Composer always installs the `require` and `require-dev` of the "top-level" or root package by default. It won't install the `require-dev` of a `required` package unless you traverse to that install and manually `composer install` in someone else's directory.