# How can I ensure that the package I am writing will be in require-dev of the target application?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am writing a package that is meant to be installed only on developer local machines. What can I do to make sure it appears next to other packages in require-dev like phpunit etc.

Also why would I even bother listing any dependencies in require-dev of my package since they will never be installed anyways in the target application??

My composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "alquesadilla/my-package-name",
  "description": "Some thing to help you in your local development.",
  "type": "library",
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "email": "email@email.com",
      "homepage": "http://someurl.com"
    }
  ],
  "bin": ["bin/enforce"],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "alquesadilla\\MyClass\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.1.*",
    "exussum12/coverage-checker": "0.7.*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do to make sure it appears next to other packages in require-dev like phpunit etc.

You can't.

The only way you could would be by means of an installer script in the downstream `composer.json`, but that would mean that you would need a way to enforce this, and there's none that I am aware of.

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#installer-events.

> Also why would I even bother listing any dependencies in require-dev of my package since they will never be installed anyways in the target application??

See [What is the difference between require and require-dev sections in composer.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19117871/1172545).