# What do I do when "Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content." when trying to install Ignition on laravel via composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install ignition in laravel via composer

```
composer require --dev facade/ignition
```

but it keeps giving me this error message:

```
Using version ^1.6 for facade/ignition
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for facade/ignition ^1.6 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition[1.6.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install filp/whoops 2.5.0
    - Can only install one of: filp/whoops[2.4.0, 2.1.13].
    - Can only install one of: filp/whoops[2.4.0, 2.1.13].
    - Can only install one of: filp/whoops[2.4.0, 2.1.13].
    - facade/ignition 1.6.0 requires filp/whoops ^2.4 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install filp/whoops 2.4.1
    - Installation request for filp/whoops (locked at 2.1.13, required as ~2.0) -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[2.1.13].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: try installing it via the cli `composer require facade/ignition`

Answer (score 2):

You can't have both filp/whoops 2.5.0 and facade/ignition 1.0-dev installed on the same Laravel app, because ignition requires version ^2.4 of whoops so remove your manually installed version of whoops and let ignition installs the correct version for itself as defined in the package's `composer.json`.

```
{
    "name": "facade/ignition",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/facade/ignition",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.4" // Here
    },
}
```

Remove filp\whoops like so

```sh
composer remove filp/whoops
```

Then install facade/ignition

```sh
composer require --dev facade/ignition
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I believe Ignition requires Whoops to work.  I believe it may be more an issue of the version required not being compatible.

Comment: Yes, ignition requires filp/whoops version ^2.4, and OP is installing 2.5.0, removing whoops and letting ignition install it as a dependency is a way to make sure the correct version of whoops is installed

Comment: the `--dev` flag means the package is only needed during development (e.g. using mockery or phpunit during testing).  it does not mean "grab the latest development version".  see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735836/4468423) for more information.